# Want to add new key value in each nested object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have one nested JavaScript object and I want to add new key value in each nested object. So basically I have to create custom function to adding it.

**My Input Object:
**

```
const obj = {
    name: {
        final: {
            val: 'yes'
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Object:
**

```
const outObj = {
    id: 1,
    name: {
        id: 1,
        final: {
            id: 1,
            val: 'yes'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  If the levels of nesting aren't known then you'd likely need to write a recursive function that loops over the object properties and recurses into any properties which themselves are also objects.

Comment: HI,
Yes I have tried to do with recursion concept but didn't success with different different test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is basic recursion. You figure out if any properties of the object is an object and you loop over that one and so on.

```js
const obj = {
  name: {
    final: {
      val: 'yes'
    }
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  name: {
    final: {
      val: 'yes',
      age: 22,
      address: {
        city: 'Noida',
        age: 23
      }
    },
    age: 18
  },
  age: 20
}


const addKey = (obj, key, value) => {
  Object.values(obj).forEach(val => {
    if (val && typeof val === 'object') addKey(val, key, value);
  });
  obj[key] = value;
}

addKey(obj, 'id', 1);
addKey(obj2, 'id', 2);

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Hi,
I appreciate your answer !!
Its worked but with different test case it is not working.
const obj = {
  name: {
    final: {
      val: 'yes',
      age: 22,
      address: {
          city: 'Noida',
          age: 23
      }
    },
    age: 18
  },
  age: 20
}

Can you please check with this one.

Comment: Looks fine to me with that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursive function and reduce to get the output:

```js
const obj = {
  name: {
    final: {
      val: 'yes'
    }
  }
};
const addId = (obj, id = 1) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    acc.id = id;
    acc[key] = (typeof val === 'object' && val !== null) ? addId(val, id ) : val;
    return acc;
}, {});



const outObj = addId(obj);

console.log(outObj)
```